# Python Tkinter Multiple Commands

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently working on a GUI using Tkinter and Python. One of the windows I create has two buttons on it: one to restart a separate python script and the other one to shut down the whole program.

When I hit the "restart" button, I'd like it to run the restart code, and then destroy the window that has the two buttons on it. I saw something else on SO that let you run two commands at once through a button click but I can't seem to get it to work. Right now the code for the button is:

```
buttonRestart = Button(restartWindow, text = "Restart", width = 8,
    height=3, command = lambda: self.restartExternal() and
    restartWinow.destroy)
```

When executed, it seems that the `restartExternal` code is working, but it doesn't destroy the window as well. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a method that calls the two methods. Tere's no shame in creating an extra function for this. It's a much more maintainable solution that trying to cram a bunch of code into a lambda.

```
def on_restart(self):
    self.restartExternal()
    self.restartWinow.destroy()

buttonRestart = Button(..., command = self.on_restart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `self.restartExternal() and restartWindow.destroy` you could do `[self.restartExternal(), restartWindow.destroy()]`.  This way, it will call `restartWindow.destroy()` whatever `self.restartExternal()` returns, whereas how it is, if `self.restartExternal()` returns False, Python doesn't even check to see if `restartWindow.destroy` is True or False.  Besides that, `restartWindow.destroy` isn't even called in yours, because you left out the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

The answer proposed by Bryan looks reasonable, but  with minimum changes - you can feed the list of functions to lambda function, like this:

```
buttonRestart = Button(restartWindow, text = "Restart", width = 8,
    height=3, command = lambda: [self.restartExternal(),
                                 restartWinow.destroy()] )
```

In my opinion, it looks better for two functions, at least.